# ATG create component and set logging dynamically

Tags: java, atg

I'm using ATG 9.4 and trying to modify our promotions engine so that we can set the filter properties per promotion rather than on the global QualifierService directly.

Basically what I've done is added properties to Item Discount repository items for each filter flag available on the QualifierService. Then I've subclassed ItemDiscountCalculator and overridden priceItems(). I read the flags from pPricingModel, construct a new Qualifier object, and put it in the pExtraParameters map with the key ItemDiscountCalculator.EXTRA_PARAM_QUALIFIERSERVICE. I then call super.priceItems()

This works 100% perfectly for what I'm trying to do - however, when I construct the new Qualifier, I use the setLoggingXXX methods to reflect whatever the levels are on the global QualifierService, but there's no logging from these new objects.

I assume this has something to do with registering the objects with nucleus and therefore whatever logging components it uses, but I haven't been able to find what I need to do to register them or just at least allow Qualifier to do its natural logging.

Below are the relevant lines of code:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void priceItems(List pPriceQuotes, List pItems, RepositoryItem pPricingModel, Locale pLocale, RepositoryItem pProfile, Order pOrder, Map pExtraParameters) throws PricingException {
    if (isLoggingTrace())
        logTrace("Entry - CustomItemDiscountCalculator.priceItems()");

    Qualifier qualifierService = getQualifierService(pPricingModel);

    if (pExtraParameters == null) {
        pExtraParameters = new HashMap();
    }

    pExtraParameters.put(ItemDiscountCalculator.EXTRA_PARAM_QUALIFIERSERVICE, qualifierService);

    super.priceItems(pPriceQuotes, pItems, pPricingModel, pLocale, pProfile, pOrder, pExtraParameters);

    if (isLoggingTrace())
        logTrace("Exit - CustomItemDiscountCalculator.priceItems()");
}

private Qualifier getQualifierService(RepositoryItem pPricingModel) {
    if (isLoggingTrace())
        logTrace("Entry - CustomItemDiscountCalculator.getQualifierService()");

    Qualifier qualifierService = new Qualifier();

    /* Get global component at /atg/commerce/pricing/QualifierService */
    Qualifier defaultQualifierService = getQualifierService();

    /* Shallow clone the global QualifierService component */
    qualifierService.setPMDLCache(defaultQualifierService.getPMDLCache());
    qualifierService.setClosenessQualifierItemDescriptorName(defaultQualifierService.getClosenessQualifierItemDescriptorName());
    qualifierService.setExactlyPromotionLoopThrough(defaultQualifierService.isExactlyPromotionLoopThrough());
    qualifierService.setLoggingDebug(defaultQualifierService.isLoggingDebug());
    qualifierService.setLoggingError(defaultQualifierService.isLoggingError());
    qualifierService.setLoggingInfo(defaultQualifierService.isLoggingInfo());
    qualifierService.setLoggingTrace(defaultQualifierService.isLoggingTrace());
    qualifierService.setLoggingWarning(defaultQualifierService.isLoggingWarning());
    qualifierService.setNucleus(defaultQualifierService.getNucleus());
    qualifierService.setPricingModelProperties(defaultQualifierService.getPricingModelProperties());
    qualifierService.setPricingModelRepository(defaultQualifierService.getPricingModelRepository());
    qualifierService.setServiceInfo(defaultQualifierService.getServiceInfo());

    /* Set any promotion specific qualifier properties */
    Boolean curFilterValue;
    if (isLoggingDebug()) {
        logDebug("Setting qualifier properties for promo: " + pPricingModel);
    }

    curFilterValue = (Boolean) pPricingModel.getPropertyValue("filterForQualifierDiscountedByAnyDiscountId");
    qualifierService.setFilterForQualifierDiscountedByAnyDiscountId(curFilterValue);

    // ... copy the rest of the QualifierService filters

    if (isLoggingTrace())
        logTrace("Exit - CustomItemDiscountCalculator.getQualifierService()");
    return qualifierService;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LogListener[] logListeners = defaultQualifierService.getLogListeners();
for (LogListener[] logListener : logListeners) {
    qualifierService.addLogListener(logListener);
}
```